# Get specific attribute value from multiple divs with same classname on page load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with HTML something like this.
I want to hide the background from the class swatch-option, and render the option-label in the div.

But I am not able to get the option-label.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('div.swatch-option').hasClass('color')) {
    console.log($(this).attr('option-label'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="swatch-attribute swatch-layered color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
  <div class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">
    <a href="#" aria-label="Black" class="swatch-option-link-layered">
      <div class="swatch-option color " tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="49" option-label="Black" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="#000000" style="background: #000000 no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" aria-label="Red" class="swatch-option-link-layered">
      <div class="swatch-option color " tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="50" option-label="Red" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="Red" style="background: Red no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I am trying. But it displays undefined. There are many more divs on the page with `class = "swatch-attribute swatch-layered"`, and similarly many more divs with classes `swatch-attribute-options` and `swatch-option`. So it is a bit complicated. Can anyone help me to get the value so that I disable the background and put value equals to option label

Comment: I would do : $('div.swatch-option').each(function() { if($(this).hasClass('color')){

                                console.log($(this).attr('option-label'));

                            }});

Comment: Thanks guys for helping so fast, the approved answer was the one that came first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('div.swatch-option.color').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('option-label'));
});
```

With above snippet, you'll get all divs with classes `.swatch-option` and `.color` - then iterate over them and access their attributes with `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `$(this)` has no context in your code, you should loop through the divs then the `this` will refer to the div :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.swatch-option.color').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).attr('option-label'));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="swatch-attribute swatch-layered color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
  <div class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">
    <a href="#" aria-label="Black" class="swatch-option-link-layered">

      <div class="swatch-option color " tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="49" option-label="Black" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="#000000" style="background: #000000 no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" aria-label="Red" class="swatch-option-link-layered">
      <div class="swatch-option color " tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="50" option-label="Red" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="Red" style="background: Red no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My post was here before yours :)

Comment: @hsz, why do you think that delay of few seconds or min is duplicate answer? I see only difference is when you posted yours that time others are editing theirs. So there is no matter of copying answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over all `swatch-option` div having `color` class and check `option-label` attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.swatch-option.color').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('option-label'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swatch-attribute swatch-layered color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
<div class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">
   <a href="#" aria-label="Black" class="swatch-option-link-layered">                                                            
      <div class="swatch-option color " tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="49" option-label="Black" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="#000000" style="background: #000000 no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
   </a>
   <a href="#" aria-label="Red" class="swatch-option-link-layered">
     <div class="swatch-option color " tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="50" option-label="Red" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="Red" style="background: Red no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @hsz, How much is the time difference between your and mine? Is there a possibility of same answer by two different people? have you created code snippet in your answer and does it take time?

Answer (score 0):

> ONLY USE THIS ANSWER IF YOU WANT A ELSE condition too.

I have used `.each` function to find all `div.swatch-option` and using the `if()` condition I have only taken account of the div which has the class `.color` if don't want it you can remove that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.swatch-option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('color')) {
    // Added this if() condition considering there are other div's which don't have the class `color`
      console.log($(this).attr('option-label'));

    }else{
       //the think you want with other div's whithout the .color class
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swatch-attribute swatch-layered color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
  <div class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">
    <a href="#" aria-label="Black" class="swatch-option-link-layered">
      <div class="swatch-option color " tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="49" option-label="Black" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="#000000" style="background: #000000 no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" aria-label="Red" class="swatch-option-link-layered">
      <div class="swatch-option color " tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="50" option-label="Red" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="Red" style="background: Red no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
      <div class="swatch-option" tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="50" option-label="test" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="Red" style="background: Red no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
      <div class="swatch-option " tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="50" option-label="test" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="Red" style="background: Red no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you get all the `div.swatch-option` elements and then check if they have an extra class?  That's a step down in performance and speed from simply getting the correct elements in the first place with `$('div.swatch-option.color')`

Comment: No, that changes nothing.  Unless you're going to do something with the divs that do not have the class `color` then it's pointless, slower and less performant.

Comment: Have a look at the (now accepted) answer from **hsz**.  The `if` statement is simply not required and making you parse every single div with the class `swatch-option`, instead of just targeting the correct ones.

Comment: @Archer you are right bro, I just forgot that first. My bad. ty for rectifying that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could apply an id attribute to the class

```
<div class="swatch-option color " id="color" tabindex="-1" option-type="1" option-id="50" option-label="Red" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="Red" style="background: Red no-repeat center; background-size: initial;"></div>
```

And the you could do something with the ID like so

```
var id = $("div.swatch-option").prop("id");
$("div.testSection").each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    // do something with the id...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just writing the answer which I wrote using the approved answer as per my requirement -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
                            $('div.swatch-option.color').each(function() {
                                var labelFetch = $(this).attr('option-label');
                                $(this).css('background',"none");
                                $(this).append(labelFetch);
                            });
                        });
```